# Oracle enable/disable jobs inside procedure with schema name included

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs

I need to specify my schema name inside DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE function,
**DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('myjob');** is working well but what if i have same named job belong different schemas? How can i specify my schema + job name inside DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ?

i tried **DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('myschema.myjob');**
 but it doesnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You're running `DBMS_SCHEDULER` connected as some user.

If you want to enable job that belongs to e.g. user Ayberk, then you'd connect as `ayberk` and run `DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('myjob')`.

If you want to enable job that belongs to user Littlefoot, connect as `littlefoot` and run `DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('myjob')` (but this time it'll affect job that belongs to `littlefoot`).

Why would user `ayberk` do *anything* with `littlefoot`'s jobs?

Comment: I have a table inside my page with all jobs and this table has all users.I want to enable/disable all the jobs with single user like admin user.

Comment: Can't test it myself, but - see whether `grant create any job`privilege helps. Your "admin" user should be granted that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE**, 
 I tried **Sys.Dbms_Scheduler.Enable (Name   => 'myschema.myjob');** and it works for me. :)